# update specific value of ng-repeat with angularJS and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to update 'Num' of '$code',using PHP and AngularJS; but it updates only the last ng-repeat value, and not the clicked one.

html file:

```
  <ion-list ng-repeat="x in names| filter: {Num: thisX}:true">
          <ion-item> 
          <div class="item item-divider center-text" ng-model='x.Code'> {{x.Code}} </div>
  <ion-item>
  <b>Date</b> <span class="item-note">  {{x.Date}} </span>
  </ion-item>
         <a class="button button-info" ng-click="update()">Update</a>
        ...
```

app.js

```
$scope.update = function(){ 

                 $http.post("http://localhost/deb/update.php",
                  {
                    'Code' :$scope.x.Code,                 
                  }
                  ).success(function(data){
                    alert(data);  
                 $scope.thisX = $state.params.Num; 
                  });  
           }
```

update.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  
     if(count($data) > 0)  
 {   
      $Code = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Code);                 
    $query = "UPDATE sale
    SET 
    Num=Null WHERE Code='$Code'"; 
      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      {  
           echo "modification réussie ...";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Error';  
      }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the `x` as parameter to function

```
<a class="button button-info" ng-click="update(x)">Update</a>
```

use that parameter to assign the `Code` value

```
$scope.update = function(x){ 

                 $http.post("http://localhost/deb/update.php",
                  {
                    'Code' : x.Code,                 
                  }
                  ).success(function(data){
                    alert(data);  
                 $scope.thisX = $state.params.Num; 
                  });  
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need, it solves my problem, thank you so much

Comment: @SalamSalam no problem, make sure to upvote and mark as right answer if this helped :D

Comment: Of course I will do, I m just waiting for the delay (12min). Thank you so much